# Creating a WYSIWYG editor - Checking if selected text has tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically I made a decent WYSIWYG editor and it works flawlessly. Last thing I need before publishing it is that if I press on text that is editable, and it already has tags (Bold/Italic/underline etc etc) then the Bold button should be marked.

Atm if I have a bolded word: **BETY** for example
And I want to add a T, I will press where I want the T and type out T. (T will be automatically bolded the way I coded it). But I have no functionality regarding making the bold button marked so the user realises that bold is activated.

Is there any JS/jQuery event that triggers when I press at a word wrapped in tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the contenteditable attribute for your WYSIWYG editor, or you are using JavaScript/JQuery code so the tags are inserted into the page (because it is WYSIWYG I think you do one of the mentioned) it seems to be a really trivial question and I will redirect you to the JQuery API selectors documentation http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ to catch your tags and  the events doc to hook on the good event http://api.jquery.com/category/events/ http://api.jquery.com/click/

If your problem is more complicated and you think it can't be solved with those suggestions, please add some more informations.

Edit : Actual solution because op's editor is using execCommand

When the user release the mouse button on the text you are watching (release so it will be triggered when click and when he ended a selection), you test if one of the execCommand has been executed on the selection.
In the toggle, you manually trigger this function so the button will be actualised.
For more informations about the possible commands :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Example.3A_a_simple_but_complete_Rich_Text_Editor

```
$('div.editable').mouseup(function() {
    if(document.queryCommandState('bold')){
        $('#toolbox #bold').wrap('<b></b>');
    } else {
        if($('#toolbox #bold').parent().is('b')) {
            $('#toolbox #bold').unwrap();
        }
    }
});

function ToggleBold() {
document.execCommand('bold',null,false);
        $('#colorpalette').fadeOut('fast');
    $('div.editable').trigger('mouseup');
}
```

Comment: I am using contenteditable.
And I have created a "hover" toolbox (MS Word-like). 
And this will show only when text is marked (I have a function that checks everytime I click if text is marked, I could probably use this to check if the selection has tags, but unfort it only returns the string and not the full html) But my marker (according to other solutions) should return HTML and then my problem would be easy...

HOWEVER, this would mean that if I did NOT select any text and just pressed in a bold tag, it would not work coz I have no selection to check if its bold.. I have no idea what to do

Comment: When you create any tags (Bold/Italic/underline etc etc), you add on the newly added tag a .click() which correspond to the onClick event. This .click() handler will make the button corresponding to the tag has "activated".

Comment: Could you possibly give me a example/js fiddle?
Because im not really understanding.

I am using the exec command to make Bold etc.

You want to add a Click event onto the tag, how is this possible?

Comment: `$('b').live("click",function(){
//Code that runs if i click text thats bolded
});`

Doesn't work if thats what you meant?

Comment: `$('b').on("click",function(){
alert('Bold is here');
});`
Works, but only for all tags that already excist, not the ones I create newly =/

Comment: Ok not sure you was using the exec command, please make a fiddle with what you have now. I will see how I could add the missing part.
ps : please do not do multiple comments if you don't have to, there is an edit command to help you when you forgot something.

Comment: @user2274247 have done it for the bold command, think you could go for the over, will edit my first answer with the modification.

Comment: @user2274247 Your solution is not working on mozilla firefox in the jsfiddle + it was the solution I suggest in the beginning... 
Why did you remove your comment with the jsfiddle?
When people are kind to you you could at least be a little grateful.

Comment: Thanks alot, this is amazing! Just gotta get it to work with pics now :P But I should be able to take it from here :)

Comment: Hmm how can I add this to several options tho? Atm I tried copying the code and just using I and U tags similairly, it works however it doesnt update in the toolbox directly like with Bold, only after i reselect it?

Comment: Just look at my answer, you have to add a bit of code in each toggle function.

Comment: But how can i do this with images?
`
    if(document.queryCommandState('bold')){
            //$('#toolbox #bold').wrap('<b></b>');
      $("#bold").attr("src","img/Bold_C.png");
        } else {
            if($('#toolbox #bold').parent().is('b')) {
                //$('#toolbox #bold').unwrap();
       $("#bold").attr("src","img/Bold_A.png");
            }
        }
`
Doesn't work :(

Comment: if($('#toolbox #bold').parent().is('b')) The problem come from there, my solution was with tags <b> </b> not with an img, just adapt the test.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ToggleBold() {
    document.execCommand('bold',null,false);
    $('b').on("click",function(){
        //make the B in toolbox bold
    });
}
```

Is how i solved it :P was quite easy

EDIT: NEVERMIND this does NOT work as intended =/